# loading a page without changing the url

Tags: php, redirect, seo

I have too many `RewriteRule` inside `.htaccess`.

Now i like to remove those `RewriteRule` and use php to load or redirect my link.

For that i use `header` but when i use it, my original urls in the browser are changing.

For example:
My original link: `http://test.com/something/someID`, and when i use header, it change to : `http://test.com/page.php?id=`

Bottom line i need something like vbseo (vbulletin) to management my link without using `RewriteRule`, but of course  i have the below code inside `.htaccess` to redirect all my link to some specific page.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't give any headers. By default redirected links remain the same. (even though the server redirects them, it's transprent to the client). So you need to pass it to index.php but with a GET value of the original route.

So...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    #If requested filename is not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    #If requested filename is not a directory
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So `example.com/this/is/a/test` would redirect to `example.com/index.php?route=this/is/a/test` which then you can check in your index.php file and reroute however you want based on that `$_GET['route']`

Comment: My problem is that i don`t know have to display other page inside index without `header`.

Answer (score 0):

Im not exactly shure if this is what you asked for:

You could use a class like the Codeigniter URI class to get the single segments of your URI:

[URI Class Source](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/URI.php)

[URI Class Description](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html)

With the given segments you can now deside in your application what to do without hardcoding it into the .htaccess

Comment: CodeIgniter works with `.htaccess` as well. The question is what you want to do with it...